# Is there a way i can assign the value shown by the date picker widget to a variable of type "Date"?

Tags: android

I'm creating an app for the android OS that allows the user to pick a Date. I want to be able to store the date the User picks in a mm/dd/yy form . I know there is a variable type called date. How do i assign the value shown by the picker to the date variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Time variable :

```
Time t = new Time();
t.dayOfMonth = dialog.getDayOfMonth();
t.month = dialog.getMonth();
t.year = dialog.getYear();
t.normalize( false );
```

and then use a simple date formatter or the format method of Time to format it in mm/dd/yy

```
String s  = t.format( "your pattern" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get it in String type just parse it to `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`